# Snowflake SSO with OKTA using python

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, okta, connector

I am trying to run snowflake using python and i don't want to authenticate through external browser each time i run a query.
I saw there is a possibility of Native SSO — Okta only i have tried that using the code below:

```
 with snowflake.connector.connect(
        user="user",
        password="password",
        authenticator='https://<okta_account_name>.okta.com',
        account = "account_name",
        #token=access_token
```

I get an authentication error each time,even tho my credentials are correct.
I thought about replacing the password with access_token gained from okta authentication
is it a better way?

using okta token,simulating externalbrowser authenticator

Comment: Is your Snowflake account configured to use Native Okta?

Comment: Make sure to disable Okta MFA for the user who uses Native SSO authentication with client drivers.

Comment: I'm not sure about the configuration to use okta native,how do I set it up?

Comment: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Setup-SSO-Using-Okta-with-Snowflake-new-URL-format
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use#native-sso-okta-only

Comment: yes, i have done that but i get the following error|"errorCode":"E0000022","errorSummary":"The endpoint does not support the provided HTTP method","errorLink":"E0000022","errorId":"oaeASX3cuc4SVWKjn7YXv-Q7A","errorCauses":[]}

Comment: If you do not use native okta and just pass authenticator=externalbrowser, do you get a Pop up of your browser tab, requesting for authentication?

If yes, once the authentication is passed, do you get the snowsight landing page? Also let me know when you pass in the authentication with your okta credentials, do you enter the MFA code  on okta end?

Comment: Yes i do get the pop up requesting for authentication.
for the second question i just get an error. maybe using oauth will be better
getting snowflake/okta access token and using it right?